# How do you return Alamofire results on the same background thread in swift?

Tags: swift, multithreading, core-data, alamofire

I'm using core data in a MacOS app. I am trying to update properties of some of the objects in a background thread using either Alamofire or URLRequest. The problem is that the response is always on a different thread so I cannot access the context to save the changes to the database.

Here's the function I use to retrieve a stock quote from Yahoo Finance:

```
func getYahooQuote2(symbol: String, queue: DispatchQueue, completion: @escaping (QuoteParent) -> Void) {
    let stockURL = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=" + symbol
    let request = AF.request(stockURL, parameters: ["quoteResponse": "result"])
    request.responseData(queue: queue) { (response) in
        guard let data = response.value else {return}
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let quoteParent = try decoder.decode(QuoteParent.self, from: data)
            if quoteParent.quoteResponse.error != nil {
                //print(quoteParent.quoteResponse.error)
            } else {
                completion(quoteParent)
            }
        } catch {
            var quoteParent = QuoteParent()
            quoteParent.quoteResponse.error?.code = "ERROR"
            quoteParent.quoteResponse.error?.description = error.localizedDescription
            completion(quoteParent)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the function that I call after the app loads:

```
func updatePrices() {
    //Run this if either this is the first time, or the stock market is open
    //firstTime is a bool variable initially set to true. This way the function will execute right away the first time, and then every 5 minutes after that during stock market hours. This should run as long as the stock market is open and keep investment prices updated every 5 minutes.
    while firstTime || Functions().isMarketOpen(date: Date()) {
        if firstTime {
            delay = 0.0 //No delay if this is the first time. Let's get the udpated prices now.
        } else {
            delay = 300.0 //If this isn't the first time, then we'll wait 5 minutes (300 seconds)
        }
        firstTime = false //Set the flag after the first iteration
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: delay)            
            guard let app = NSApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}
            app.persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask() { (moc2) in
                guard let mvc = app.myViewController else {return} //main UI ViewController
                let investFetch = self.getInvestFetch() //Gets an NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>
                do {
                    if var investments = try investFetch.execute() as? [InvestmentMO] {
                        investments = investments.filter({$0.needsPriceUpdate}) //Filter investments to just those that need a price update. This reduces the number of calls to the Yahoo Finance API.
                        mvc.setProgressIndicator(maxVal: Double(investments.count - 1)) //Set the progress indicator on the main UI.
                        for investment in investments {
                            mvc.reportProgress(msg: "Updating investment prices") //Shows incrementing progress indicator and status message on main UI
                            let symbol = investment.symbol
                            moc2.perform {
                                //From here we request data from Yahoo Finance. This request is made using the background thread being used by the moc2 context.
                                //I've tried to capture the thread/queue in this variable below, which I pass to the Alamofire function
                                let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "background", qos: .background, attributes: .concurrent)
                                Functions().getYahooQuote2(symbol: symbol, queue: queue, completion: {(quoteParent) -> Void in
                                    //Now we have a problem, because despite my passing the queue above, the code in this closure runs on a different background queue. Not the one where the moc2 context lives. Thus, I am unable to access the context to make the changes to the Investment object in this iteration.
                                    if let result = quoteParent.quoteResponse.result {
                                        if result.count > 0 {
                                            let stock = result[0] //This is the object from Yahoo Finance that has the data I want to update the InvestmentMO object with.
                                            if let priceDec = stock.regularMarketPrice {
                                                    if investment.isFault {
                                                        print(investment.priceDate.date.toShortDateString) //Filling the fault
                                                }
                                                investment.price = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: priceDec)
                                                if let priceTime = stock.regularMarketTime {
                                                    investment.priceDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(priceTime))
                                                } else {
                                                    investment.priceDate = NSDate()
                                                }
                                                for holding in investment.holdingArray.filter({$0.isOpen()}) {
                                                    holding.holdingPrice = investment.price
                                                    holding.holdingValue = holding.quantity.multiplying(by: holding.holdingPrice)
                                                    holding.gain = holding.holdingValue.subtracting(holding.cost)
                                                    if holding.gain.decimalValue != 0 && holding.cost.decimalValue > 0 {
                                                        holding.gainPerc = holding.gain.dividing(by: holding.cost)
                                                    } else {
                                                        holding.gainPerc = 0
                                                    }
                                                    if let account = holding.account {
                                                        let sum = account.holdingArray.map({($0.holdingValue.decimalValue)}).reduce(0, +)
                                                        let costtot = account.holdingArray.map({($0.cost.decimalValue)}).reduce(0, +)
                                                        account.accountValue = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: sum)
                                                        account.cost = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: costtot)
                                                        account.gain = account.accountValue.subtracting(account.cost ?? 0)
                                                        if account.gain?.decimalValue != 0 && account.cost?.decimalValue ?? 0 > 0 {
                                                            account.gainPerc = account.gain?.dividing(by: account.cost!)
                                                        } else {
                                                            account.gainPerc = 0
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                for trade in investment.tradeArray.filter({!$0.executed}) {
                                                    trade.tradePrice = investment.price
                                                    trade.tradeValue = investment.price.multiplying(by: trade.quantity ?? 0)
                                                    trade.gc = trade.getGC()
                                                    trade.tradeCost = trade.tradeValue?.adding(trade.gc ?? 0)
                                                    trade.nc = trade.getNC()
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                            
                        }
                        if moc2.hasChanges {
                            mvc.setReadyString(rdst: "Saving Changes")
                            try moc2.save()
                        }
                        mvc.setProgressIndicator(maxVal: 0)
                        mvc.setReadyString(rdst: "Ready")
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                    print("What happened?")
                }
                
            }
        }        
}
```

Is there a way to return the results of the Yahoo Finance API call in the same thread as the context? That way I could iterate through all the investments that need a new price, update the prices and after the loop finishes save all the changes to the database. I can easily do this in the main thread, but of course that blocks the UI, so I want to do this in the background.

Here's the getInvestFetch function:

```
func getInvestFetch() -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> {
    let investFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Investment")
    let fetchDate = Date().addMinutes(min: -5).nsDate
    let pred1 = NSPredicate(format: "(investmentType == 1 OR investmentType == 2) AND holdings.@count > 0")
    let pred2 = NSPredicate(format: "priceDate <= %@", fetchDate)
    let investPred = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: [pred1, pred2])
    investFetch.predicate = investPred
    investFetch.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    return investFetch
}
```

Here's the functions in ViewController I use to update the UI from background threads:

```
func setProgressIndicator(maxVal: Double){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if maxVal > 0 {                
            self.progressIndicator.maxValue = maxVal
            self.progressIndicator.doubleValue = 0
            self.progressIndicator.isHidden = false
        } else {
            self.progressIndicator.isHidden = true
            self.setReadyString(rdst: "Ready")
        }
    }
}

func setReadyString(rdst: String, delay: Double = 0){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.readyString = rdst
        }
    }        
}

func reportProgress(prog: Double = 0, msg: String = ""){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if msg != "" {
            self.setReadyString(rdst: msg)
        }
        if prog > 0 {
            self.progressIndicator.doubleValue = prog
        } else {
            self.progressIndicator.doubleValue += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I never did find out how to return the callback to the same thread with either Alamofire or URLRequest, but I did find a way to update the investments from Yahoo Finance API. Instead of making a call to Yahoo Finance API for each investment I make a single call to Yahoo Finance and request multiple tickers at once. That way I can process the changes to the investments from the background thread in the Alamofire or URLRequest result. I'd still like to know how to get data from web api's and return results to the same thread that called them.

Here's the new price updater function:

```
func updatePrices() {
    //Run this if either this is the first time, or the stock market is open
    //firstTime is a bool variable initially set to true. This way the function will execute right away the first time, and then every 5 minutes after that during stock market hours. This should run as long as the stock market is open and keep investment prices updated every 5 minutes.
    while firstTime || Functions().isMarketOpen(date: Date()) {
        if firstTime {
            delay = 0.0 //No delay if this is the first time. Let's get the udpated prices now.
        } else {
            delay = 295.0 //If this isn't the first time, then we'll wait 5 minutes (300 seconds)
        }
        firstTime = false //Set the flag after the first iteration
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: delay)
        guard let app = NSApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}
        guard let mvc = app.myViewController else {return}
        mvc.setReadyString(rdst: "Updating Investments")
        app.persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask() { (moc2) in
            let investFetch = self.getInvestFetch() //Gets an NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>
            do {
                if var investments = try investFetch.execute() as? [InvestmentMO] {
                    investments = investments.filter({$0.needsPriceUpdate}) //Filter investments to just those that need a price update. This reduces the number of calls to the Yahoo Finance API.
                    if investments.count > 0 {
                        Functions().updateInvestmentsFromYahoo(investments: investments)
                    } else {
                        mvc.setReadyString(rdst: "Ready")
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
                print("What happened?")
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

And the new function to update the prices from Yahoo Finance:

```
func updateInvestmentsFromYahoo(investments: [InvestmentMO]) {
    if let app = NSApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        var symbols = ""
        for investment in investments {
            if symbols == "" {
                symbols = investment.symbol
            } else {
                symbols += ",\(investment.symbol)"
            }
        }
        let stockURL = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=\(symbols)"
        let request = AF.request(stockURL, parameters: ["quoteResponse": "result"])
        request.responseData() { (response) in
            guard let data = response.value else {return}
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let quoteParent = try decoder.decode(QuoteParent.self, from: data)
                if quoteParent.quoteResponse.error != nil {
                    print(quoteParent.quoteResponse.error!)
                    print("What happened?")
                } else {
                    if let stocks = quoteParent.quoteResponse.result {
                        guard let moc2 = app.mocBackground else {return}
                        guard let mvc = app.myViewController else {return}
                        mvc.setProgressIndicator(maxVal: Double(stocks.count - 1))
                        guard let mvc = app.myViewController else {return}
                        mvc.setProgressIndicator(maxVal: Double(stocks.count - 1))
                        for stock in stocks {
                            guard let symbol = stock.symbol else {return}
                            mvc.reportProgress(msg: "Updating \(symbol)")
                            moc2.perform {
                                let invFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Investment")
                                invFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "symbol == %@", symbol)
                                do {
                                    guard let investments = try invFetch.execute() as? [InvestmentMO] else {return}
                                    guard let investment = investments.first else {return}
                                    if let priceDec = stock.regularMarketPrice {
                                            if investment.isFault {
                                                print(investment.priceDate.date.toShortDateString) //Filling the fault
                                        }
                                        investment.price = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: priceDec)
                                        if let priceTime = stock.regularMarketTime {
                                            investment.priceDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(priceTime))
                                        } else {
                                            investment.priceDate = NSDate()
                                        }
                                        for holding in investment.holdingArray.filter({$0.isOpen()}) {
                                            holding.holdingPrice = investment.price
                                            holding.holdingValue = holding.quantity.multiplying(by: holding.holdingPrice)
                                            holding.gain = holding.holdingValue.subtracting(holding.cost)
                                            if holding.gain.decimalValue != 0 && holding.cost.decimalValue > 0 {
                                                holding.gainPerc = holding.gain.dividing(by: holding.cost)
                                            } else {
                                                holding.gainPerc = 0
                                            }
                                            if let account = holding.account {
                                                let sum = account.holdingArray.map({($0.holdingValue.decimalValue)}).reduce(0, +)
                                                let costtot = account.holdingArray.map({($0.cost.decimalValue)}).reduce(0, +)
                                                account.accountValue = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: sum)
                                                account.cost = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: costtot)
                                                account.gain = account.accountValue.subtracting(account.cost ?? 0)
                                                if account.gain?.decimalValue != 0 && account.cost?.decimalValue ?? 0 > 0 {
                                                    account.gainPerc = account.gain?.dividing(by: account.cost!)
                                                } else {
                                                    account.gainPerc = 0
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        for trade in investment.tradeArray.filter({!$0.executed}) {
                                            trade.tradePrice = investment.price
                                            trade.tradeValue = investment.price.multiplying(by: trade.quantity ?? 0)
                                            trade.gc = trade.getGC()
                                            trade.tradeCost = trade.tradeValue?.adding(trade.gc ?? 0)
                                            trade.nc = trade.getNC()
                                        }
                                    }
                                } catch {
                                    print(error)
                                    print("What happened?")
                                }
                                if let stock2 = stocks.last {
                                    guard let symbol2 = stock2.symbol else {return}
                                    if symbol == symbol2 {
                                        //This is the last stock, so let's save the changes now
                                        if moc2.hasChanges {
                                            do {
                                                mvc.setReadyString(rdst: "Saving Changes")
                                                try moc2.save()
                                                mvc.setProgressIndicator(maxVal: 0)
                                            } catch {
                                                print(error)
                                                print("What happened?")
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
                print("What happened?")
            }
        }
    }
}
```